# Can we have a mycelium tech-tree?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology

Considering the impressive complexity of the vast mycelium networks that permeate the world, I was wondering if it would be possible for a civilization to use mycelium as a "coding" mechanism to create organic technology. Perhaps, they develop an "internet" of sorts using mycelium networks as a basis. Their use of metal would largely be limited to war technology, but they would largely be an organic civilization. Is this possible?

Comment: if you say "In my world X is possible" then X will be possible in your world, similarly if you say "in my world X is impossible" then X will be impossible in your world. Whether something is or isn't possible is a question of what rules you choose to impose on your world. If you want your world to have a mycelium based internet then your world can have a mycelium based internet. Why don't you build that world and see what interesting stories you can tall within.

Answer (score 3):

**Drugs. Maybe Houses Too.**

The only example that comes to mind is how Penicillin is produced by a fungus. It is believable that other funguses could be genetically modified to produce other useful drugs.

Of course this is a far-cry from a fungus-only tecnholosphere. It is much harder to believe the things they used to design the drugs or genetically modify the fungus are themselves made of fungus.

Perhaps if your aliens are able to intuitively interface with other life forms (See Lillith's Brood) on a cellular level then this becomes more believable.

Anything other than chemical manufacture sounds unbelievable. It does sound like a lot of fun though. I want a world where people drive around in big mushrooms and live inside even bigger mushrooms.

[image]

Zoom zoom losers here I come. Get on it.

---

**Extra:** As Demigan points out, it is believable that specially bred fungus is used as a building material. For example you build a mesh frame over a hillock and then impregnate it with spores. The fungus draws nutrients from the soil and eventually makes a hard dome around the hill, complete with foundations that extend into the soil.
Then you dig out the hill and live inside.

It is difficult however to imagine why people would build their houses like this in the first place. It requires generations of breeding fungus. It also requires to build the frame out of *SOMETHING*. Why not just build the whole house out of that something?

Perhaps there is simply not much wood or stone in the environment.

[image]

Comment: What about Prototaxites and selective breeding of fungi? Would certain fungi have the structural capability to form house-like structures?

Comment: @Demigan That is a good point. I can imagine a fungus that is designed to grow inside a hollow framework and then become very hard.

Comment: A site I find not too trustworthy cited something like 25 feet for "telephone poles" fungi without branches. What if you combine those with other fungi? One for stability and structural integrity, one that hangs inbetween them to form the walls and ceiling? Perhaps you can also use them for preservation: use cut wood for structural integrity, have fungi grow around and into it and preserve the wood against the elements. Perhaps this is what already happens and most wood is consumed in the fungi-rich environment without these fungi protecting it.

Comment: @Demigan A friend of a friend of mine once offered to sell me some fungus to get me, as he put it, "so damn high". 25 feet is pretty tall. That must be what he meant.

Comment: @Demigan I think inventing new types of fungus is allowed, since we probably need to start in a world with little accessible wood or stone in the first place, to encourage the use of fungal architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of the Yuuzhan Vong from Star Wars? They had an entirely organic tech tree, so maybe take some of their ideas (amphistaffs for weapons and door membranes?). Additionally, it’s your magic world, fungus can do whatever the heck you want it to do.